# When a skill has a flat bonus, does that apply to the Wild Die as well?

Tags: savage-worlds

I recently played an expert surgeon with the Healer trait and Professional Healer.  That meant I rolled 1d12+3 for Healing checks.

So if I rolled my check as d12 (skill) and d6 (wild) and I rolled a 1 on the skill die and a 5 on the wild die, would my total be 5 (the unmodified wild die) or 8 (the wild die modified by my skill bonus)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes - Wild Cards (like PCs) take the highest of the roll of the normal die and their Wild Die (often a d6, but can actually be larger based on various Edges) and apply skill/attribute/other modifiers as normal.  So your total would be 8 in this case.

And yes, you can roll an Ace on the Wild Die (it can explode).

Comment: Clear answer.  ZING!

Answer (score 9):

Always roll both dice at the same time (Trait and Wild).
Take the highest result after Aces of the two.
Then add your modifiers.

```
(skill:d12,wild:d6)+3 => (1,5)+3 => 5+3 => 8
```

Note this works for unskilled as well

```
(skill:d4,wild:d6)-2 => (1,2)-2 => 2-2 => 0
```